# Can I switch PCIe slot of boot NVME SSD to another without having to reinstall Windows?

Tags: boot, pci-express, nvme

My computer has PCIe (NVME) SSD with an adapter that was placed in Slot 2 but now, I need to switch it to Slot 3. Can I do that without having to reinstall OS after the switch?

This question might be obvious to someone, but I would like to make sure before making a mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There should be no difference when swapping slots, apart from maybe having to check boot order in BIOS again.

Apart from that, modern windows (7 or newer and its server counterparts) are quite flexible when it comes to hardware changes. I had success even swapping the motherboard on installation done in a PCIE NVME drive.